# Find the item in an array that meets a specific criteria if there is one (Perl)?

Tags: arrays, perl

Is there a Perl idiom for finding the item in an array that meets a specific criteria if there is one?

```
my $match = 0;
foreach(@list){
   if (match_test($_)){
      $result = $_;
      $match = 1;
      last;
      }
   }
$match || die("No match.");
say $result, " is a match.";
```

The example seems a bit awkward. I expect Perl to have something to handle this more cleanly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) is what you are looking for:

```
my @results = grep {match_test($_)} @list;
```

`grep` returns the subset of `@list` where `match_test` returned true.  `grep` is called `filter` in most other functional languages.

if you only want the first match, use `first` from [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util).

```
use List::Util qw/first/;

if (my $result = first {match_test($_)} @list) {
    # use $result for something
} else {
    die "no match\n";
}
```

Comment: Also, the expression [`@array ~~ $scalar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) is true when `$scalar` is in `@array`.

Comment: @daxim => assuming you have a perl new enough to have smartmatching (5.10+)

Comment: @C.W.Holeman II: I gave an example of both cases in my answer.

Comment: @daxim et al:  From 5.10.1+ the order of ~~ is important.  Thus it needs to be `$scalar ~~ @array`   NB.  To help I think of ~~ as synonym for "in".

Answer (score 6):

If there could be multiple matches:

```
 my @matches = grep { match_test($_) } @list;
```

If there could only be one match, [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util)'s 'first' is faster (assuming a match is found):

```
 use List::Util 'first';
 if (my $match = first { match_test($_)} @list)
 {
      # do something with the match...
 }
```

Comment: faster on very large arrays, but that's not the common case

Comment: It's also no faster if there are zero results, since every element still needs to be checked.