# Perl programming regarding maps

Tags: perl, dictionary

I'm reviewing my homework and I am confused on a statement from my notes. If someone could explain what the tilde is doing as well as the s/\d that would be great.

```
@name = ("Name: Bruce Grade: 85", "Name: Jill Grade: 87");
@GradeA = map { $entry = $_; $entry = ~ s/\d{2,3}/A/; $entry} @GradeA;
```

Comment: The accepted answer tells what `=~` and what `~~` represent in Perl, duplicate of [What does " ~~ " mean in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094916/what-does-mean-in-perl)

Comment: @Prix I don't see ~~ here

Comment: @user4035 no you don't but you see `=~` don't you? Have you also read my comment prior the link? Guess not.

Comment: @user3353920 you can use the [**`Edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22161152/edit) link below your question to update new information to it.

Comment: `= ~` is two operators: assignment and bitwise negation. Seeing as it is followed by a regex substitution it is likely that you have confused it with `=~`, which is the binding operator, used with regexes (among other things).

Comment: @Prix Look at TLPs comment. Looks like, "`=~`" is not the same as "`= ~`" (with space between them)

Comment: @user4035 you're pointing it to the wrong person. regardless the OP is trying to run a regex and he wants to know what `=~` does on it obviously. Typo happens.

Comment: Thank you, that does help explain the tilde. I am confused on after the tilde as well. What is that statement doing? My confusion is the s/\d{2,3} part.

Comment: Thank you everyone! As I was practicing I was putting the space between the = and ~ and that is why I was getting numbers instead of my intended output. Your explanations and guidance were beneficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`= ~` is two [operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html): assignment and bitwise negation. Seeing as it is followed by a regex substitution it is likely that you have confused it with `=~`, which is the binding operator, used with regexes (among other things).

Assuming that `= ~`  is a typo, the `map` statement simply applies a regex substitution `s///` to a list of strings, changing 2-3 numbers (e.g. `12` or `123`) to `A`. It is written somewhat redundantly, and can be reduced to

```
s/\d{2,3}/A/ for @GradeA;
```